# GloVe Import error - Corpus - Unable to import

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have tried everything possible while importing Corpus from Glove - I tried Pip Install and the Pip3 Install from the Zip file. Nothing seems to work. Please do help.

Comment: Please share, what all you have tried with the system details.

Comment: I run an Ubuntu 20.04. Python 3.8, Anaconda environment. I have tried pip install glove that immediately gave me an error. Then a solution on github asked to try pip3 install....zip file which installed glove. But then when I was trying to import Corpus from glove it gave me an import error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Glove from mittens as well. Mittens use the same algorithm as GloVe and vectorizes the objective function.

Install:

```
pip install -U mittens
```

Import:

```
from mittens import GloVe
```

For Details - https://github.com/roamanalytics/mittens#mittens

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out.

Comment: Feel free to Upvote. And select as an answer - if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only thing that worked was to install Glove using:

```
pip install glove-python-binary
```

Then import it using:

```
from glove import Corpus, Glove
```